# Minimum g9 led current

Tags: led

I am trying to find out the minimum current of a LAP 220V 2.78W g9 led. Is there an IV curve available for this product? None of the data sheets I have found show any minimum current requirements or an IV curve.

I have carried out simple current experiments using a Variac and have recorded at 185V around 10mA and then on another day, same lumen output,185V at around 1mA, same LED same setup etc. Could the LED have been damaged or is there another reason why the current has varied substantially?

Does anyone know the minimum current requirement of a g9 led or can link an IV curve?

Comment: You probably won't find anything like a current/voltage chart for LED bulbs.  They aren't just LED - they have some kind of regulation in them to limit the current.

Comment: Is "lap" the brand name? If so, shouldn't it be capitalised? Do you have a manufacturer's website? As JRE says, if it's a light bulb then it *contains* LEDs but is not an LED itself.

Comment: I've found a few IV curves for normal 3V LEDs just can't seem to find one for these 220V g9 LEDs.

Comment: As others indicate, this is probably an LED circuit system, not an LED, and the system is designed to operate with 220 VAC and not at 185 VAC. You are probably attempting to use it in an unmanaged way and are getting different results because it's not designed to work the way you are operating it. If you need something different, find and buy it. Or design your own system to meet your goal.

Comment: If the lamp is advertised as "220 V", and is intended to replace G9 halogen lamps, then it should work when connected directly to 220 V, with no additional current limiting. These things are sold to the general public who don't know that LEDs need current-limiting resistors, so must work with no extra parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've found a few IV curves for normal 3V LEDs just can't seem to find one for these 220 V G9 LEDs.

As explained in the comments, it's not an LED, it's a lamp using LEDs.

[image]

*Figure 1. Screengrab from Big Clive's [Teardown of a G9 LED lamp](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fQG3u4MzNjk).*

[image]

*Figure 2. The results of Big Clive's reverse engineering.*

You can work out the impedance of the 470 nF capacitor from \$ Z = \frac {1}{2 \pi fC} \$ where f is your mains frequency.

---

From the comments:

> Does the circuit system mean I can directly connect to a 220 V supply and the circuit will regulate the current required?

The schematic (which is for Clive's lamp - not yours) shows that there is no regulator. Current is limited by the impedance of the 470 nF capacitor and
the 330 Ω resistor. As voltage is reduced the current will fall too.

Comment: Does the circuit system mean I can directly connect to a 220V supply and the circuit will regulate the current required?

Comment: See the update.